# When is the null vector in the range of an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Excluding the null vector from the domain, can
 the null vector be within the range of a matrix 
if the eigenvalues of that matrix are all non-zero?

Explanation:
I have developed two matrix representations of
a linear operator, one based on a power series 
and the second based on Laguerre Polynomials.
I thought they should be equivalent, but the 
power series has a homogeneous solution 
while the Laguerre representation is triangular 
with the same value on all the diagonal elements, 
i.e. all of its eigenvalues  are the same and non-zero.

Comment: If $M\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ for some $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$ then $\mathbf{x}$ is - by definition - an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’ll take it as a definitive “no” to my question. I guess I’ll have to search for a flaw in my representation.